# Computing Conditional Probability (Poisson Random Variables)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The number of red and blue cars that go through a given intersection in an hour is a Poisson-distributed random variable with $\lambda$ = 10.  What is the probability, conditionally, that at most three cars that go through the intersection are red given that ten blue cars entered in that hour?

I should note, I understand how the Poisson distribution works, but I am not sure how to do it conditionally.

Comment: Are the numbers of *each* Poisson distributed? And are the random variables independent? Or is it that the total has Poisson distribution? If so, are red and blue equally likely (implausible)?

Comment: @AndreNicolas There does not seem to be any information on independence or whether it is the total that has Poisson distribution.  There was another section I left out from the question which notes:  What assumptions were made?  I assume the idea is to construct the rest of the missing information arbitrarily as it is very much an applied probability question.  Sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: Presumably the number of cars is Poisson, and the color is independent with some fixed probability?

Comment: Yes, that seems right.  Perhaps for simplicity perhaps we can say that they are equally likely?  The question seems to be partly about making some semi-reasonable assumptions.

Comment: Is it possible to provide the source of the question (instead of making people wonder what is in it)?

Comment: It is from a printed out note so unfortunately there is no available link.

Comment: You have all the info. The number of red and blue is poisson with $\lambda=10$. Exactly 10 are blue, the rest must be red. The number of green, pink or yellow you neither know nor care.